# Tkinter Scrollable canvas create additional scroll area on top

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, frame

I'm quite new to **Tkinter** on python3, and trying to make a **scrollable frame on top of a canvas**.
I'm able to create it for default windows size, with no problem. But when the **windows maximized**, the canvas suddenly add **extra scrollable area** on top and I have been looking for way to remove it / keep my scrollable frame on top.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1500x800")
        self.configure(background="#303030")


class Table(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, rows=2, columns=2):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, background="#36363d")

        # Set table as list of rows
        self.table = []
        for row in range(rows):

            # Create list to store cell info in a rows
            current_row = []
            for column in range(columns):

                label = tk.Label(self, text="", borderwidth=0, width=columns, bg="#474756", )
                label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1, )

                # Append cell (column) into rows
                current_row.append(label)

            # Append rows into whole table
            self.table.append(current_row)

        for column in range(columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)


class ScrollablePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, bg="red")    # THIS TO EMPHASIZE THE CANVAS,

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, *args, **kw)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", tags="self.frame")

        # Dynamic frame setup
        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.frame_conf)
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.frame_width)

        # Bind canvas to mousewheel
        self.canvas.bind("<Enter>", self.bound_to_mousewheel)
        self.canvas.bind("<Leave>", self.unbound_to_mousewheel)

    def frame_conf(self, event):
        """
        Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
        """

        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def frame_width(self, event):
        """
        Function to adjust canvas's frame upon expand (can't use pack)
        """

        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_frame, width=event.width)

    def mouse_wheel(self, event):
        """
        Capture mouse wheel changes to scroll page
        """
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 60), "units")

    def bound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.mouse_wheel)

    def unbound_to_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")


class PageTwo(ScrollablePage):

    def __init__(self, master):

        # Create page
        super().__init__(master, bg="#36363d")

        # EXAMPLE CONTENT
        controller = tk.Frame(self.frame, bg="#474756", width=0.9 * 1500, height=200, bd=0,)
        controller.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20, pady=10)

        self.table = Table(self.frame, rows=20, columns=10)
        self.table.pack(side="top", fill="both", padx=20, expand=1)


class MainContent(tk.Frame):

    # Setup main content's stacked-frame
    frames = {}

    # main_content_classes = [PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour, PageFive, PageSix, PageDefault]  # << ORIGINAL ONE
    main_content_classes = [PageTwo]

    def __init__(self, master):

        # Create main content's frame
        super().__init__(master)

        # Place main content's frame in main window
        self.place(x=150, y=130, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.83)

        # Create grid inside main content frame
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Stacking pages in main content
        for FrameClass in MainContent.main_content_classes:
            page_name = FrameClass.__name__
            frame = FrameClass(self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            MainContent.frames[page_name] = frame


class Datalab:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        main_window = MainWindow()
        MainContent(main_window)
        main_window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Datalab()
```

I Include some link to image (can't post directly) to illustrate

- default window size - scrollable canvas on top
- maximized window - canvas created additional scroll area on bottom (marked red : canvas)
- maximized window - canvas created additional scroll area on top (marked red : canvas)

Thanks in advance

Comment: create minimal working example so we could run it as see problem.

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to correctly format code - currently you have wrong indentions.

Comment: if frame is smaller then canvas then you have to see red canvas below frame - or use `canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_frame, height=event.height)` to change frame's height automatically (similar to `width`).

Comment: Please verify that above code snippet is [mcve].

Comment: @Nae I have updated the code, please check it again, thanks

Comment: @furas I tried to set `height=event.height` but then I can't scroll anymore, seems it doesn't work out

Comment: This is still not a [mcve]...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem and found that `vsb.get()` method returns tuple `(0.0, 1.0)` when everything is shown in the window (maximized, or not many items within scroll area). Don't know how dirty this solution is, but this worked for me.

Mousewheel should take effect only when scrollbar is scrollable:

```
def mouse_wheel(self, event):
    """
    Capture mouse wheel changes to scroll page
    """
    if self.vsb.get() != (0.0, 1.0):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 60), "units")
```

Comment: Wow.. thanks ... how did u discover that... it **works** !!

I was using extra padding but now I dont need that anymore :>

Comment: I was looking for the good implementation of the scrollable frame with a lot of widgets inside and yours worked really well. So I'm glad we both helped each other:)